New install of jenkins on RHEL 8 won't start due to failed to map segment from shared object error
Jenkins setup: clean install on RHEL 8 using these steps:
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key
sudo yum install fontconfig java-17-openjdk
sudo yum install jenkins
sudo systemctl edit jenkins
Environment=“JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk”
sudo systemctl start jenkins
fails to start
sudo journalctl -xe
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/JNA/temp/jna17258145716752850398.tmp: /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/JNA/temp/jna17258145716752850398.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object

Do you get a different error if you remove the whole /var/lib/jenkins/.cache directory and systemctl start again?

No, In fact the .cache directory has no files in it before starting jenkins and no files are left in it after it fails :/

What's your default java alternatives --config java? I have a sneaky suspicion that setting JAVA_HOME in the service override might be a bit late.
